# Add listview items to specific columns in Visual Basic by default

Tags: vba, listview

I need to sort a schedule of flights into a listview which the user cannot edit

i know how to add listview items within the program when it is running but i need to have the schedule built into the program.

Thanks

Comment: which Office programm do you use? It's an easy one in Access but hard in Excel.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Basic Express

Comment: and why do you post under tag VBA? vb.net has a dedicated control called Timer for that. You will find in the toolbar. Simply add to your form, set the interval property to milli seconds (so 1.000 for 1 second) and enable it in the form load event (by default it should be disabled). You can add a event handler to the timer.tick event then which occurs always when the interval is over (so each second if you set the interval to 1.000)